# Hoiw can i remove all ip addresses from Azure SQL Server Firewall Rules , but still login via SSMS?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a number of sql servers in Azure and under Networking Section in the area

"Firewall rules
Allow certain public internet IP addresses to access your resource"

there are a number of ip addresses added which allows a user to connect via SSMS.

Now if the address is not there SSMS gives you the option to add it , I dont want to allow that . So is there a way to allow the user to login lets say via Microsoft Entra Id and have no ipp addresses in that section ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. IP exceptions in the firewall are completely separate from authentication.

The option for users to add their IP when connecting with SSMS will only work if they have the appropriate roles to edit the firewall rules. If they aren't already in the firewall rules, and they can't add their IP, then they can't connect.

Comment: So basically there is no way to keep the firewall rule list clear ?   Unless I clear it every day and force users to add their ip and if they cant then call administrator ?

Comment: With the firewall active, there need to be rules there to allow people to connect. Why do you want the list to be clear? We manage ours by having the user's name and the date in the rule name, then periodically purging any rule that can't be linked to an active user. It's never empty, but this allows us to remove old rules with minimal disruption to current users.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a way to allow the user to login let's say via Microsoft Entra Id and have no IP addresses in that section ?

**NO, you can't allow user to connect the server without whitelisting the IP**

When setting up a new server in Azure SQL Database, a server-level firewall is automatically implemented to block access to the public endpoint. These firewall rules are designed to allow clients to connect to the entire server, granting access to all the databases hosted on that server.

***To be able to create and manage IP firewall rules for the Azure SQL Server, you will need to either be:***

- *SQL Server Contributor role*
- *SQL Security Manager role*
- *The owner of the resource that contains the Azure SQL Server*

Without these roles Users can't add their IP to server and If IP is not whitelisted, they can't Connect to the server.

For more information check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql) document